# jQuery toggle replace anchor tag value on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to swap out button text on click. The function of a button is to toggle a `<div>`. Is it possible with jQuery to set up two instances of button text and swap them out on toggle?

This is where I am so far:

```
$('#showmodule').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
    $('#module').slideToggle()
});
```

Comment: *the functions of button is to toggle a*, an example or something would be easy for understanding

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: *a `<div>`*, I added some missing backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in your case, is add spans inside of your anchor link, and toggle those, such as the following.

```
<a href="#" id="showmodule">
    <span>Default Text</span>
    <span style="display : none;">Toggled Text</span>
</a>
```

And the javascript would look something like this.

```
$('#showmodule').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('span', this).toggle(); // This line will toggle the spans inside of the link

    $('#module').slideToggle()
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same thing, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it... I've also done a similar thing creating two buttons with show/hide.

Comment: this is very interesting way of doing it though. How does it know which span to toggle? Nevermind.... key word 'toggle'

Comment: I personally think, that by having everything contained inside of a single anchor, instead of side by side as alternative buttons, it allows for your code to be more concise by grouping the two blocks of toggle text inside of the same element. As far as a cleaner way of doing it, the only other thing I could imagine doing is using attributes on the actual element. <a href="#" toggle-on="Default Text" toggle-off="Toggled Text"></a>

Comment: Sorry, as far as knowing which span to toggle, the .toggle() method in jquery naturally hides visible elements, and shows invisible elements. By defining the second span as display : none, jquery will then always have an offset one visible, one invisible, that it will toggle between on every click :)

Comment: Replacing `addClass` with `toggleClass` would probably take care of his *next* bug.